# Thread exception on SelectedNode = .Nodes[0]

Tags: c#, user-interface, thread-exceptions

Why do i get System.Threading.ThreadStateException?

```
void setupTree(TreeView tv, MyObj o)
{

    tv.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        tv.Nodes.Clear();
        tv.Nodes.Add("<root>").Tag = o;
        tv.SelectedNode = tv.Nodes[0]; //it happens here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Has the TreeView had its handle created yet?

Could you post a short but complete program to demonstrate this?

Comment: What do you mean? wouldn't it must have its handle created to make it to the 3rd tv line? I probably wont post up an example but i'll try clean it up enough to show a short example.

Comment: i'm sure this helps noone but this may answer your handle question. http://i40.tinypic.com/eh0p3q.jpg

Comment: Right, so it's already actually showing. Okay, that can't be it. When we've only got a single method to go by, we don't know whether it's been made visible or anything like that.

Comment: different error but it happens on the same line and my thinking was the same while writing this. It probably wont give you an idea but here you go. http://www.pastie.org/440598